# How to upload file from python Flask web app to Supabase Storage

Tags: python, flask, supabase, supabase-database

I want to be able to upload a file from Flask to Supabase Storage, but it only has documentation for the javascript api [link to docs](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload).

Also, I can't find any examples or any open source project that does that. Here it is my function to upload:

```py
def upload_file(self):
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect('/')
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect('/')
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    # upload to supabase storage
    return file.path
```

Comment: Where is the request object being stored from the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from storage3 import create_client

url = "https://<your_supabase_id>.supabase.co/storage/v1"
key = "<your api key>"
headers = {"apiKey": key, "Authorization": f"Bearer {key}"}
storage_client = create_client(url, headers, is_async=False)

def upload_file(self):
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect('/')
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect('/')
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)

    buckets = storage_client.list_buckets()
    bucket = buckets[0]
    return bucket.upload(filename, file)
```

I didn't find official docs for python upload.
Didn't test the code above so appreciate any feedback.
I've based this on the github repo https://github.com/supabase-community/storage-py and the docs here https://supabase-community.github.io/storage-py/api/bucket.html